# SSRS tooltips in a column

Tags: reporting-services

I have a very nice admin matrix report "Report Users by Site" that you can drill down from Site, to Category, to Report name.

Where is shows a report was run 7 times yesterday (for example) I would like to hover over that '7' and get a list of the 7 users who ran that report.

I can do [=Fields!UserName.Value] which races through the 7 names displaying just the last one. I tried Split etc with no luck.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I did something similar before, share the structure of your dataset in order to help you.

Comment: @RichardBSmith Do you want to display all 7 Usernames within that group in the tooltip?

Comment: I see you tried Split, but have you tried Join? Seems like that would make better sense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()` to join a list of things together. For the tooltip on the textbox, use something like:

```
=join(lookupset(Fields!Row.Value & "|" & Fields!Column.Value, Fields!Row.Value & "|" & Fields!Column.Value, Fields!Value.Value), ", ")
```

In this example, `Fields!Row.Value` is what my row is grouped on, and `Fields!Column.Value` is what my column is grouped on.

[image: Tooltip]

Comment: Sorry nothing returned ...
just hacking around I happened upon this that almost works ...
in that I get a list of names (sadly all the same) ...

=join(lookupset(Fields!UserName.Value
, Fields!UserName.Value
, Fields!UserName.Value
, "Reports"),"" + vbcrlf)

Comment: @RichardBSmith - I've updated the answer to give you something that should work. It's working on my report.